# Human task in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

I am newbie to Jbpm. I have integrated the JBPM with spring, I have one confusion.

JBPM is beneficial because in case we have to add node we do not have to code.But what  in case if human task. Do i have to create a form in JSP and then pass the values to process somehow or we can only see the processes in jBPM console. and provide the inputs there only

Please help me to understand this

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think that you are mixing things here. 
If you have business processes you separate the definition of the business side from the technical side, in other words you separate "what needs to be done" with "how to technically do it". If you change your business processes and you add a new system to system connector, you don't need to code anything if the connector already exists, you just need to add the correct parameters to make it work. If you add a new User Task, you can use the Form Modeller to provide the UI for the end user to add the required information to complete the task, again you don't need to code. If you really need to work with JSPs you will need to build something similar than the jbpm console that allows you to provide forms generated by the form modeller. 
HTH
Regards

Comment: Hi ,

Is there any form modeller in jbpm 3?

Comment: No I don't think so, we are working on the jbpm 6 version already jbpm3 is too old